# My code needs to store my inputs in an array and then display them, but it only displays my last input, not all of them. How can I solve this?

Tags: arrays, assembly, tasm, dosbox

When I press 1 on keyboard I need to input more names of 5 characters, store them in an array, and when I press two, it should display all the names I've written. The only problem is that when I press two, only the last name is displayed. I think they are overwriting each other, but I can t find out why. Can someone help, please? Here is the code that should store the names:

```
scrienume:
    ; print prompt
    mov dx, offset prompt
    mov ah, 9
    int 21h
    ;Read the input string one character at a time
    mov cx, 5
    mov si, offset nume
read_char:
    mov ah, 1
    int 21h
    cmp al, 0ah ; check if input character is newline
    je end_of_string
    mov [si], al ; store input character in array
    inc si
    loop read_char
end_of_string:
    mov byte ptr [si], '$' ; add null terminator
    jmp bucla
```

and here is the code that should display them:

```
lista:
    mov si, offset nume ; move offset of names array to si
    print_names:
        mov dx, si ; move contents of si (memory location of name) to dx
        mov ah, 9 ; print string function
        int 21h ; call MS-DOS function
        add si, 5 ; increment si to next memory location
        cmp byte ptr [si], '$' ; check if the current name is the last one
        jne print_names ; if not, repeat
    jmp bucla ; return to main loop
```

I tried to store every name written in an array, but they are overwriting each other, so my program is not displaying all of the outputs.

Comment: That code reinitializes `si` to the beginning of the array each time, so of course it is going to overwrite the start of the array each time.  If you want it to do something different, then don't tell it to start over each time.

Comment: Inputting text/names into an array can be done in any language, so, work out what you want the program to do.  You don't have to think in assembly to work that out.

Answer (score 0):

### Errors in *scrienume*

- If *nume* is the address for the array of 5-character names, then you can only use that particular address for inputting the very first name. For inputting the second name you should initialize SI at `nume + 6` and for the third name at `nume + 12`, and so on... Each time **6** more since you store 5 characters and 1 $-sign.
- If you allow an early out from the input loop (`cmp al, 0ah` `je end_of_string`), you will loose that nice 6-byte-per-datum setup. And BTW, under DOS you need to check for **13** to see if there's a newline.

### Error in *lista*

This code will only display the very first record! The `add si, 5` instruction will move to a location where there is indeed a $-sign that your code will notice followed by *not* repeating the loop.
Because of the overwriting problem in the input loop, displaying the very first record, displays the last name.

---

### This is a possible solution

Define a word-sized variable that will hold the address to the current record in the array.

```
  mov  numePointer, offset nume

  ...

scrienume:
  mov  dx, offset prompt
  mov  ah, 09h
  int  21h
  mov  cx, 5
  mov  si, numePointer
read_char:
  mov  ah, 01h
  int  21h
  mov  [si], al
  inc  si
  loop read_char
  mov  byte ptr [si], '$'
  inc  si
  mov  numePointer, si ; numePointer += 6
  jmp  bucla

  ...

lista:
  mov  dx, offset nume
print_names:
  mov  ah, 09h
  int  21h
  ; (*)
  add  dx, 5 + 1
  cmp  dx, numePointer ; check if the current name is the last one
  jb   print_names
  jmp  bucla           ; return to main loop
```

(*) You might want to insert a newline for readability of the output:

```
  push dx
  mov  dl, 13          ; carriage return
  mov  ah, 02h
  int  21h
  mov  dl, 10          ; linefeed
  mov  ah, 02h
  int  21h
  pop  dx
```

Comment: I changed the scrienume and lista as you said but I have the same problem.Where should I declare numePointer and add the newline for readability? Here is my main loop :                               bucla:
    ;Move cursor to the next line
    mov dl, 0dh
    mov ah, 2
    int 21h
    mov dl, 0ah
    int 21h
    ;Display menu
    call display_menu
    mov ah, 1
    int 21h
    cmp al, '1'
    je scrienume
    cmp al, '2'
    je lista
    cmp al, '3'
    je sterge
    cmp al, '4'
    je exit
    jmp bucla

Comment: Nevermind, I figured it out. Thank you for your time and for your response. Now I will try to figure out how can I delete a name from the list by index.