# What is the next step to my project Assembly x86

Tags: assembly, x86-16

I am trying to fix the code for my project but i am a little overwhelmed. [This is the last question I asked about my code](https://stackoverflow.com/q/75139774/21022612).
I am here to upload the whole code:

```
.model small
.stack 100h

.data
indexul db 2 dup (0)
invalid db "Indexul introdus este invalid!",0,'$'
string db 'Introduceti indexul numelui pe care doriti sa-l stergeti:',0,'$'
punct db '.$'
prompt db 'Introduceti un nume:',0,'$'
list db 'Lista cu numele este:',0,'$'
nume dw 50 dup(0)
numes dw 0
numeIndex db 13, 10, 49, 46, 36

numePointer dw 50
menu db "Alege o optiune:",13,10
     db "1. Nume",13,10
     db "2. Lista cu numele",13,10
     db "3. Sterge un nume",13,10
     db "4. Exit",13,10,'$'

.code
start:
    mov al, 0
    ;INITIALIZE DATA SEGMENT.
    mov  ax, @data
    mov  ds, ax
    mov numePointer, offset nume
    call clear_screen
bucla:
    ;Move cursor to the next line
    mov dl, 0dh
    mov ah, 2
    int 21h
    mov dl, 0ah
    int 21h
    ;Display menu
    call display_menu
    mov ah, 1
    int 21h
    cmp al, '1'
    je scrienume
    cmp al, '2'
    je lista
    cmp al, '3'
    je sterge
    cmp al, '4'
    jmp exit
    jmp bucla

    mov dx, offset numePointer

scrienume:
  mov  dx, offset prompt
  mov  ah, 09h
  int  21h
  mov  cx, 5
  mov  si, numePointer
read_char:
  mov  ah, 01h
  int  21h
  mov  [si], al
  inc  si
  loop read_char
  mov  byte ptr [si], '$'
  inc  si
  mov  numePointer, si ; numePointer += 6
  jmp  bucla






lista:
mov  byte ptr [numeIndex + 2], "1"
  mov  dx, offset nume
print_names:
  push dx                        ; (1)
  mov  dx, offset numeIndex
  mov  ah, 09h
  int  21h
  inc  byte ptr [numeIndex + 2]  ; "1" -> "2" -> "3" ...
  pop  dx                        ; (1)

  mov  ah, 09h
  int  21h
  add  dx, 5 + 1
  cmp  dx, numePointer ; check if the current name is the last one
  jb   print_names
  jmp  bucla           ; return to main loop



sterge:
    ; Prompt user for position of name to delete
    mov dx, offset string
    mov ah, 09h
    int 21h
    ; Read position from user
    mov ah, 01h
    int 21h
     sub  al, 49      ; AL=["1","9"] 1-based input -> AL=[0,8] 0-based index
  mov  ah, 6
  mul  ah          ; -> AX = {0,6,12,18,24,30,36,42,48}
  add  ax, offset nume
  cmp  ax, numePointer
  jnb  invalidPosition
  mov  di, ax
  lea  si, [di + 6]
  mov  cx, numePointer
  sub  cx, si
  cld
  rep movsb
  mov  numePointer, di
  dec  numes
  jmp  bucla
  
invalidPosition:
    ; Display error message
    mov dx, offset invalid
    mov ah, 09h
    int 21h
    jmp bucla





exit:
    ;FINISH PROGRAM.
    mov  ax, 4c00h
    int 21h

;---------------------------------------------
display_menu proc
  mov  dx, offset menu
  mov  ah, 9
  int  21h
  ret
display_menu endp

clear_screen proc
  mov  ah, 0
  mov  al, 3
  int  10H
  ret
clear_screen endp
end start
```

As i mentioned in the other questions, it only deletes the last name no matter what index i input.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> ```
> ;INITIALIZE DATA SEGMENT.
> mov  ax, @data
> mov  ds, ax
> ```

You forgot to setup the ES segment register! You need it for the `movsb` instruction.

```
;INITIALIZE DATA SEGMENT.
mov  ax, @data
mov  ds, ax
mov  es, ax
```

---

> ```
> nume dw 50 dup(0)
> ```

Better define this with `db` and reserve room for at most 9 names, so 9 * (5 + 1):

```
nume db 54 dup(0)
```

Comment: Thank you so much for your patience and time.It works well now.

Comment: I have accepted the answers. Thank you!

Comment: Happy to see I could help you. On to your next project...