# Addressing a problem to my last project https://stackoverflow.com/q/75151982/21022612

Tags: assembly, x86-16, tasm

Regarding the last project i made in assembly x86 the code is working fine but i tried someting and i found that if i input just one name and try to delete it, it doesn't work and also if i input more than 10 names in the list the index is not showing properly.

I tried to point out the problem myself but i can't figure it out.

Can you guys tell me where the problem is or where should i change something?

The code:

```
 .model small
.stack 100h

.data
indexul db 2 dup (0)
invalid db "Indexul introdus este invalid!",0,'$'
string db 'Introduceti indexul numelui pe care doriti sa-l stergeti:',0,'$'
punct db '.$'
prompt db 'Introduceti un nume:',0,'$'
list db 'Lista cu numele este:',0,'$'
nume dw 50 dup(0)
numes dw 0
numeIndex db 13, 10, 49, 46, 36

numePointer dw 50
menu db "Alege o optiune:",13,10
     db "1. Nume",13,10
     db "2. Lista cu numele",13,10
     db "3. Sterge un nume",13,10
     db "4. Exit",13,10,'$'

.code
start:
    mov al, 0
    ;INITIALIZE DATA SEGMENT.
    mov  ax, @data
    mov  ds, ax
    mov es, ax
    mov numePointer, offset nume
    call clear_screen
bucla:
    ;Move cursor to the next line
    mov dl, 0dh
    mov ah, 2
    int 21h
    mov dl, 0ah
    int 21h
    ;Display menu
    call display_menu
    mov ah, 1
    int 21h
    cmp al, '1'
    je scrienume
    cmp al, '2'
    je lista
    cmp al, '3'
    je sterge
    cmp al, '4'
    jmp exit
    jmp bucla

    mov dx, offset numePointer

scrienume:
  mov  dx, offset prompt
  mov  ah, 09h
  int  21h
  mov  cx, 5
  mov  si, numePointer
read_char:
  mov  ah, 01h
  int  21h
  mov  [si], al
  inc  si
  loop read_char
  mov  byte ptr [si], '$'
  inc  si
  mov  numePointer, si ; numePointer += 6
  jmp  bucla






lista:
mov  byte ptr [numeIndex + 2], "1"
  mov  dx, offset nume
print_names:
  push dx                        ; (1)
  mov  dx, offset numeIndex
  mov  ah, 09h
  int  21h
  inc  byte ptr [numeIndex + 2]  ; "1" -> "2" -> "3" ...
  pop  dx                        ; (1)

  mov  ah, 09h
  int  21h
  add  dx, 5 + 1
  cmp  dx, numePointer ; check if the current name is the last one
  jb   print_names
  jmp  bucla           ; return to main loop



sterge:
    ; Prompt user for position of name to delete
    mov dx, offset string
    mov ah, 09h
    int 21h
    ; Read position from user
    mov ah, 01h
    int 21h
     sub  al, 49      ; AL=["1","9"] 1-based input -> AL=[0,8] 0-based index
  mov  ah, 6
  mul  ah          ; -> AX = {0,6,12,18,24,30,36,42,48}
  add  ax, offset nume
  cmp  ax, numePointer
  jnb  invalidPosition
  mov  di, ax
  lea  si, [di + 6]
  mov  cx, numePointer
  sub  cx, si
  cld
  rep movsb
  mov  numePointer, di
  dec  numes
  jmp  bucla
  
invalidPosition:
    ; Display error message
    mov dx, offset invalid
    mov ah, 09h
    int 21h
    jmp bucla





exit:
    ;FINISH PROGRAM.
    mov  ax, 4c00h
    int 21h

;---------------------------------------------
display_menu proc
  mov  dx, offset menu
  mov  ah, 9
  int  21h
  ret
display_menu endp

clear_screen proc
  mov  ah, 0
  mov  al, 3
  int  10H
  ret
clear_screen endp
end start
```

Comment: The `jmp bucla` after `jmp exit` will never be run, as you have no way of getting there. It should be `je bucla`.

Comment: Same for the `mov dx, offset numePointer` after `jmp bucla`. Since you don't have a label going there you'll never run it.

Comment: Now is a great time to up level your debugging skills.  Use single step.  At each step, verify your program's state, which includes registers and memory, including the program counter which goes to proper logic for control flow.  If the program does something you don't expect, then debug that.  Sometimes we find something unexpected, but the instructions themselves there look right, but they're getting bad data, so we back up to earlier in the program flow to find why they're getting bad data.  Repeat until its all working.